# Odd behavior replacing string with special replacement patterns in IE7|8

Tags: javascript, regex, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

I've spotted a very strange issue in IE7|8 when using special replacement patterns:

```
'moo$$e'.replace( /\$/g, '$$$$' );
'moo$$e'.replace( '\$', '$$$$', 'g' );
```

Latest Chrome:

```
 moo$$$$e moo$$$e
```

Latest Firefox:

```
 moo$$$$e moo$$$$e
```

IE7|8:

```
 moo$$$$e moo$$$$$e
```

I know that [flags parameter is nothing like a standard](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace), hence the difference between Firefox and Chrome in the second case. **I'm cool with it**.

However, what I see in IE7|8 is really odd (still second case). I tried playing with `'\x24'`, escaping and stuff but I cannot find any way to have this working as expected (`$$` stands for `$`).

I know that this could be easily done with `split()` and `join()` like:

```
'moo$$e'.split( '$' ).join( '$$' );
> "moo$$$$e"
```

but I'm really, really curious what's wrong with IE. Is there any explanation?

See the [live example](http://jsbin.com/uyuguz/2/).

Comment: Could you please describe what exactly it is that you want to do? What exactly is the problem, and what should the "right" answer look like?

Comment: For `'moo$$e'.replace( '\$', '$$$$', 'g' );`, given the non-standard third parameter, I would guess IE simply ignores it, which means it then treats the first parameter as a string and not a regex and does a non-regex replace of the first occurrence. (Note that all three browsers behave the same way when you supply an actual regex as the first param.)

Comment: @Pointy What I'm trying to do is to learn why IE7|8 gives odd results, how to detect such cases and avoid/fix them.

Comment: @oleq well using a function as the second parameter would give you much more control, because you wouldn't have to worry about the `$` semantics in the replacement string.

Comment: @Pointy: you're (most likely) right. But still... strange that there's no information about this bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Test case

I revisited the [test case](http://jsbin.com/iyuqap/1/) with results to present it as follows:

```
var results = [
  'YY'.replace( /Y/g, '$$' ),
  'YY'.replace( 'Y', '$$', 'g' ),
  'YY'.replace( 'Y', function( a, b ) { return '$$'; }, 'g' ),
  'YY'.replace( /Y/g, function( a, b ) { return '$$'; })  
];

console.log( results.join( '\n' ) );
```

---

## Results

#### Chrome

```
$$    // '$$' -> '$', global flag used, every 'Y' -> '$'
$Y    // '$$' -> '$', global flag ignored, first 'Y' -> '$'
$$Y   // '$$' -> '$$', global flag ignored, first 'Y' -> '$$'
$$$$  // '$$' -> '$$', global flag used, every 'Y' -> '$$'
```

#### Firefox

```
$$    // '$$' -> '$', global flag used, every 'Y' -> '$'
$$    // '$$' -> '$', global flag used, every 'Y' -> '$'
$$$$  // '$$' -> '$$', global flag used, every 'Y' -> '$$'
$$$$  // '$$' -> '$$', global flag used, every 'Y' -> '$$'
```

#### IE7 and 8

```
$$    // '$$' -> '$', global flag used, every 'Y' -> '$'
$$Y   // '$$' -> '$$', global flag ignored, first 'Y' -> '$$'
$$Y   // '$$' -> '$$', global flag ignored, first 'Y' -> '$$'
$$$$  // '$$' -> '$$', global flag used, every 'Y' -> '$$'
```

---

## Conclusions

1. Chrome ignores `'g'` flag as a third parameter of `String.replace` since [flags used this way don't belong to any standard](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).
2. IE assumes `$$` to be string rather that replacement control and ignores global flag in this case:

   `'YY'.replace( 'Y', '$$', 'g' );`
3. The simplest solution make sure that results are always the same is to use a `RegExp` object with flags (`/foo/flags`) as a first parameter and either string or function as a second parameter.

   If string is a second parameter, `$$` converts to `$`. If this is a function-driven replacement, there's no such conversion.